# how can i replace webkit-line-clamp property for firefox compatibility

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I want to trying to truncate a long text (in two lines) by using **-webkit-line-clamp: 2 property**.

But in firefox, the -webkit-line-clamp property doesn't work.

```
overflow: hidden;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Can you help me please. My solution works fine in chrome but **-webkit-line-clamp** doesn't support by firefox

Comment: Are you certain that FF isn’t supporting it? Could you make your code into a runnable snippet, ie with attendant HTML, as I’m worried you are using box-orient and would like to see whether a flex box solution would be more appropriate in your particular case. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This property was originally implemented in WebKit and has some issues. It got standardized for legacy support. The CSS Overflow Module Level 3 specification also defines a line-clamp property, which is meant to replace this property and avoid its issues.

Comment: Hi @Leo , i replace line-clamp property  but it doesn 't work